# windows 7 cant open files from osx mavericks server

Tags: windows, permissions, mac-osx-server, file-sharing

I have recently setup OSX Server (on Mavericks) with an external harddrive.
I have setup users and groups and created two sharepoints (public (on the internal drive), work (on the external)).

Last week everything was running fine, windows and mac users alike were able to open, copy, save files to and from the server.

Starting yesterday an issue has arisen where a windows 7 user is no longer able to open files directly from the server where she was able to before. 
 - She can copy the files from the server and then open them on her
   desktop. 
 - This is happening for both the sharepoints.
 - The public sharepoint is using ACL
 - The work sharepoint has no ACL
 - Both sharepoints are limited to SMB only

I have tried searching for and implementing various solutions but am not winning so far.

I was hoping that someone would be able to point me in a direction.

Thanks, 
Nick

Comment: What are the exact error messages you are seeing ? are there any relevant messages in the logs on both the client and the server.

Comment: On the windows machine when trying to open a pdf it will give a message saying that the file is open by another user and that it cannot be opened. When trying to open an image it gives a similar error message. 
At first I thought it may be the indexing that was causing issues so I disabled that but it didnt make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seemed to be related to anti-virus, I was unawares that the software installed on the machine was limiting access to the files (I was unaware that the anti-virus even scanned network shares these days).

Seems I was focusing my research efforts in the wrong direction.